# Can Careers feature non-developer jobs?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'd love to use Careers to find technical writing jobs, and I suspect other IT types would benefit too.  Note that I'm not asking for a big change, just an expansion to include more of the IT field.

Comment: Isn't the *raison d'etre* for Careers to be geared towards those in the IT field?

Comment: If you mouse-over the "Careers" tag, it specifically says that its' for programmers. And I've tried searching for Technical Writing jobs worldwide, and none appear at all.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm subtly getting at.  I'm not so sure that the platform should be changing its focus when it's still got work to do on the IT front just yet.

Comment: Technical Writing *is* an IT job. At least, it often is.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson There are entire big programming languages without a single job listing on careers because their community isn't on SO. Similarily the tech writing community isn't on SO (as SO is a site for programmers) so this makes little sense till SE gives that community a home somewhere.